# Struggling to formulate proofs in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

I am new to graph theory and I struggle to formulate and even get startet on proves of, what I believe, are obvious facts.

**Consider the following problem:**
Let $G = (V = A \cup B, E)$ be a bipartite graph. Show that $\delta(G) + \Delta(G) \leq |V(G)|$.

$\delta(G) := \min_{v \in V(G)} \deg(v), \; \Delta(G) := \max_{v \in V(G)} \deg(v)$

In a bipartite graph there are no edges between vertices in A and no edges between vertices in B, this is equivalent to there being no odd cycles. My initial thought for this problem was to show that if the given inequality does not hold one could always find an odd cycle, but I have not been able to show this.

Any help would be very much appreciated:)

Comment: A good place to start is with the definitions. What does $\delta(G)$ mean? What does $\Delta(G)$ mean? What is a bipartite graph? You could start by looking up the definitions and editing them into your question, so we'll know them too. Then we can help you go on from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $|A| =a$ and $|B| = b$, then $|V(G)| =a+b$ and $$\delta(G) \leq \min\{a,b\}={a+b-|a-b|\over 2}$$ and
$$\Delta(G) \leq \max\{a,b\}={a+b+|a-b|\over 2}$$